# Drawing lines between points in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, polymaps

I'm trying to draw lines between plotted points using d3.js.

Sample geojson (FeatureCollection of 3 LineString):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hgkdvbnrgmb6kak/test.geojson?dl=0

Full Existing Code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/49820rs561vneti/test.html?dl=0

Code Chunk I'm having problem with:

```
lines.append("g").selectAll("path")
  .data(d3.entries(data.features)).enter()
  .append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", path)
```

The circles are appearing but not the line to connect them together.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mistake 1:

Inside your your topojson.

```
{
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        103.79971,
                        1.3013115
                    ],
                    [
                        103.8071998,
                        1.2932586
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "type": "Feature",//this is wrong
            "properties": {} 
        }
```

It should have been:

```
{
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        103.79971,
                        1.3013115
                    ],
                    [
                        103.8071998,
                        1.2932586
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {}
        }
```

Mistake 2:

```
  lines.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(d3.entries(data.features)).enter()
      .append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke-width", "2px")
```

You can't create a line like this, for creating line you have to use a layer and add the feature to it like this(note the features are from your test.geojson):

```
d3.json("test.geojson", function(data) {
  layer1.features(data.features);//adding the features to the layer
  map.add(layer1);
```

Full working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ROl0yWWYX0yp0mO1kfhF?p=preview).

Comment: thanks cyril! this helped a lot! Question though! Is there a reason why adding the line can't be done like in normal d3 graphs (with enter, exit)? Seems like if I want lines on maps, they have to be introduced as an additional layer (which I thought will be just for topo layer, shapefiles, etc).

Comment: the error in geojson is weird though, I was using the geojson package in python to create the geojson file. And from example code at https://github.com/JasonSanford/geojson-google-maps/blob/master/README.md which has an example of a FeatureCollection (though not with LineString), it seems to be similar.

Comment: Related to the problem but more of data format: Is it more expensive/ makes more sense to have the points for the line in 1 LineString instead of 3 (the current sample data) if the points are for a single group/user.

Comment: @iukie Yeah the reason why adding a line as shown under Mistake 2 will not work is that the line is not given a starting and end position, perhaps its very difficult to get that point.(MOre over you will have to handle the translate+scale when the map zoom and pans) So the best approach is to go with layers and pass the feature to it. I don't think its possible to achieve the same in D3...

Comment: It would be good idea that you handle the points also via layer using your geojson file. This will be a good read
http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#point